# Add a computed column in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

Suppose I have the following table declaration in SQLAlchemy:

```py
class RowEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String, index=True)
```

I wish to have a computed column (say, `string_id`) that's calculated automatically from `id` (by casting it to string), but ACTUALLY exists in the DB (for example, to index over):

For example:

```py
class RowEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String, index=True)


RowEntry.string_id = CalcualatedColumn(func.cast(RowEntry.__table__.c.id, sqlalchemy.String), index=True)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You  may add `string_id` column to the model (with index created). And modify (calculate) the value for this column using sqlalchemy events (e.g. `after_insert`, `after_updated`): https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/event.html

Comment: @jorzel Thank you, but I don't want to have to make two DB calls for every insert. It would hurt performance.